# Trying to Pass numeric parameters from input to Javascript function

Tags: function, input, parameters

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="sumall"></div> 
 </div>


 <form role="form">
 <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num2">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num3">
    <input type="submit" onclick = "sumAll(num1,num2,num3)" value="OK">
 </div>
```

I am a total noob!

Trying to pass numbers from 3 input fields to a function but get no response. The console shows no errors, the alert statement displays [object HTMLInputElement]? So its returning the objects instead of the value?

Help me please???

```
function sumAll(num1,num2,num3) {
    alert(num1);
    var sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
       document.getElementById("sumall").innerHTML = "<p>" + "The number is: " + sum + "</p>";
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.value` on num1 2 3 to get the results.

```js
function sumAll(num1,num2,num3) {
    var sum = Number(num1.value) + Number(num2.value) + Number(num3.value);
    alert(sum);
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="sumall"></div> 
 </div>


 <form role="form">
 <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num2">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="num3">
    <input type="submit" onclick = "sumAll(num1,num2,num3)" value="OK">
 </div>
```